# A question about ''project onto self''

Tags: snapping

I was following a tutorial on making a doughnut. When it comes to snapping the option *Project onto Self* was missing. Also, I was in editing mode. Does anybody have any solution to this problem?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

*Include active* is the option that you are looking for

[image]

Actually, this option is split into whose two: *Include active* and *Include edited*